# Lenovo x1 carbon 3rd generation touchpad issues

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, lenovo, hardware

I am using Lenovo x1 carbon 3rd generation with ubuntu 18.04, The touch pad is behaving weird like, If you drag the pointer down to a specific point and removes the finger from the touchpad then the pointer jumps to a random position.

An example will be closing a browser tab, Drag the pointer x and remove the finger off the pad, The pointer jumps to a random position.

Is it normal, Or is there anything which can help around.

Thanks

Comment: It's not normal. Probably a 'libinput' issue. Since this piece of software is relatively new, latest version brings big improvement. Try to update it!

Answer (score 0):

The same problem forced me to switch to **Synaptics** driver. It's **deprecated** but this fact has never affected my experience.

To make your touchpad stop shaking and become more precise you may use my solution:

In `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` directory I have `40-libinput.conf` with the following content:

```
# Match on all types of devices but joysticks
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput tablet catchall"
        MatchIsTablet "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

And `70-synaptics.conf` with:

```
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Option "TapButton1" "1"
        Option "TapButton2" "3"
        Option "TapButton3" "2"
        Option "PalmDetect" "1"
        Option "PalmMinWidth" "8"
        Option "PalmMinZ" "100"
        Option "VertScrollDelta" "-125"
        Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "on"
        Option "HorizScrollDelta" "-125"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

# This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on clickpads
# and the right and middle top areas to be right / middle buttons on clickpads
# with a top button area.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
        Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "58% 0 0 15% 42% 58% 0 15%"
EndSection

# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
        MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

If this file does not exist, you should create it. Notice that the number before synaptics must be greater than the number before libinput.

You **should not** delete `40-libinput.conf` because in this case touchpad won't work at all.

P.S. A good article in which you can find out how to configure Synaptics file - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Let me try it. And i don't have the second file you mentioned.

Comment: @Comrade, just creating the file should be enough in most cases. However, if there are problems - check if the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package is installed (and install if it's not).